# Align two time series data sets on an hourly basis (Python, Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data sets that I am trying to compare.  One is measured meteorological values which are measured approximately every 15 minutes, but not at a consistent time each hour (i.e. 12:03, 1:05, 2:01 etc.).  The other data set is modelled data for the location on the hour exactly.  I would like to extract the value from the measured data which is occurs closest to the hour mark to join with the modelled data.

I currently have both sets as a DataFrame format and have created an hourly time series to use as an index.  Does anyone know of an easy way to align these without looping through all the data?

Thanks.

Using the `df.resample('H', how='ohlc')` method, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#81>", line 1, in <module>
    df.resample('H', how='ohlc')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 290, in resample
    return sampler.resample(self)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\resample.py", line 83, in resample
    rs = self._resample_timestamps(obj)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\resample.py", line 226, in _resample_timestamps
    result = grouped.aggregate(self._agg_method)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 1695, in aggregate
    return getattr(self, arg)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 427, in ohlc
    return self._cython_agg_general('ohlc')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 1618, in _cython_agg_general
    new_blocks = self._cython_agg_blocks(how, numeric_only=numeric_only)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 1656, in _cython_agg_blocks
    result, _ = self.grouper.aggregate(values, how, axis=agg_axis)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 818, in aggregate
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

A sample of my dataframe is shown below:

```
                              D
2008-01-01 00:01:00  274.261108
2008-01-01 00:11:00  273.705566
2008-01-01 00:31:00  273.705566
2008-01-01 00:41:00  273.705566
2008-01-01 01:01:00  273.705566
2008-01-01 01:11:00  273.705566
2008-01-01 01:31:00  273.705566
2008-01-01 01:41:00  273.705566
2008-01-01 02:01:00  273.705566
2008-01-01 02:11:00  273.149994
```

**EDIT:** It appears this may be an error when using python 3.3.  Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 2):

I thinks [pandas.DataFrame.resample()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) is what you need here. You can check what [method of resampling](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#up-and-downsampling) you want, for example, check 'ohlc':

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'data':[1,4,3,2,7,3]}, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2013-11-05 12:03', '2013-11-05 12:14','2013-11-05 12:29','2013-11-05 12:46','2013-11-05 13:01','2013-11-05 13:16']))
>>> df.resample('H', how='ohlc')
                     data                  
                     open  high  low  close
2013-11-05 12:00:00     1     4    1      2
2013-11-05 13:00:00     7     7    3      3
```

After that, all you need to do is use [pandas.DataFrame.join()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html).

**update** it's strange, tried it on your DataFrame:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'D':[274.261108,273.705566,273.705566,273.705566,273.705566,273.705566,273.705566,273.705566,273.705566,273.149994]})
>>> df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2008.01.01 00:01:00','2008.01.01 00:11:00','2008.01.01 00:31:00','2008.01.01 00:41:00','2008.01.01 01:01:00','2008.01.01 01:11:00','2008.01.01 01:31:00','2008.01.01 01:41:00','2008.01.01 02:01:00','2008.01.01 02:11:00'])
>>> df.resample('H', how='ohlc')
                              D                                    
                           open        high         low       close
2008-01-01 00:00:00  274.261108  274.261108  273.705566  273.705566
2008-01-01 01:00:00  273.705566  273.705566  273.705566  273.705566
2008-01-01 02:00:00  273.705566  273.705566  273.149994  273.149994
```

Works ok.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm looking for.  However, I'm running into an issue with the 'ohlc' part.  If I use 'mean' or other qualifiers the code works but 'ohlc' returns an error.  Is there any other way to get the closest value to the hour?

Comment: I added it to my question.

Comment: @HHains hm, could you add sample DataFrame?

Comment: Added as well.  Thanks for all your help.  Again, other methods like mean and max are working as expected.

Comment: @HHains you could try to narrow your error, ohlc works ok on your sample data

Comment: That's odd.  Could it be a datatype error?  I'm assuming you copied my values to create the dataframe.  My values are float type and may have more values after the decimal than got copied.
Although, I just copied the data from your screen, re-created df from your data and tried to resample using 'ohlc'.  Still returns the same error.  I don't need to call any additional libraries do I? Or call pandas implicitly (ie. import pandas *)?

Comment: what version of Pandas/python do you use?

Comment: python v3.3, Pandas v 0.12.0-py.3.3

Comment: I have python 2.7, may be that's the problem

Comment: Thanks for all your help anyways.  Can you think of any other method to take just the closest value to the hour?